# Transformar en Mayúscula la primera letra de cada palabra en MySQL

Tags: mysql

tengo una `función` en `MySQL` así:

```
    delimiter $
create function f_insertar_mayusculaMinuscula_Empleado(_id_empleado int) returns varchar(70)
begin
    declare salida varchar(70);
    declare i int;
    set i = 1;
    select concat_ws(" ",Trim(nombre),Trim(apellido_paterno),Trim(apellido_materno)) into @nombre from empleado where id_empleado = 1; /*_id_empleado;*/
    select CHARACTER_LENGTH(@nombre) into @num_Caracteres;
    set salida = @nombre;
    repeat 
        if(select substring(@nombre,i,1 = ' '))then
            set salida = salida + upper(substring(@nombre,i+1,1));
            set i = i + 1;
        else 
            set salida = salida + lower(substring(@nombre,i,1));
            set i = i + 1;
        end if;
        until i <= @num_Caracteres
    end repeat;
    return salida;
end $
```

La idea es obtener el nombre y los apellidos de una tabla con el `id_empleado` por ejemplo: **juan roberto pérez gomez** y transformarlos a este formato: **Juan Roberto Pérez Gómez**.
Pero al momento de ejecutar la `función` me retorna `null`.
comente todo el `repeat` y solo retorne la variable `@nombre` y si me retorna el nombre como esta en la base de datos (pero obviamente sin formato), por lo que el error esta en el `repeat`.
Así que si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: No es mas facil arreglar todos los nombres en este momento, y de ahora en mas agregarlos como corresponde?? de esa manera te evitas tener que ejecutar esta funcion cada vez que ejecutas un query, sobre todo si devuelves muchos datos.

Comment: Puedes usar funciones ya hechas para capitalizar las primeras letras de una cadena, por ejemplo: [MySQL Capitalize Function](http://joezack.com/2008/10/20/mysql-capitalize-function/) o bien  [MySQL Function to Capitalize the First Letter of Words in a String](http://www.roytuts.com/mysql-function-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-words-in-a-string/) u otra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a todos, ya pude resolverlo con el siguiente código:

```
DELIMITER $ 
CREATE FUNCTION f_insertar_mayusculaMinuscula(cadena varchar(45)) returns varchar(45)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE input varchar(45);

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(cadena);
    SET input = LOWER(cadena);
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE (i < len) DO
        IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
            IF (i < len) THEN
                SET input = CONCAT(
                    LEFT(input,i),
                    UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                    RIGHT(input,len - i - 1));
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN input;
    END $
```